# Как разместить файл в памяти?

Tags: файлы, память, c++, delphi

При том, что б доступ к нему был так же как и к обычному файлу на диске?

Comment: Возможно, **отобразить** файл в память? Тогда CreateFileMapping итд.

Comment: возможно это поможет.
а доступ потом к нему как? скорость доступа повысится?

Comment: о_О, или я вас неправильно понял, пожалуйста, опишите понятнее!

Comment: есть файл, к которому производится многократный доступ(открытие, чтение, запись, закрытие).
есть ли возможность повысить быстодействие, путем размещения его (содержимого) в памяти.
файл размером до сотни мегабайт.

Comment: Как вариант RAM-disk . За счёт оперативной памяти создаётся диск, на который можно закинуть файлы. Доступ к ним будет со скоростью оперативной памяти. Диску задаётся и своя буква. Т.е. полное подобие работы с логическим диском, но не на винчестере, а в оперативной памяти. Правда, всё равно файл нужно будет загружать с этого диска в остальную часть оперативки.

Comment: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2180#ov

Comment: В Linux для этого есть mmap. Похоже виндовый аналог это https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Например, ImDisk позволяет создавать диск в памяти.. и достаточно просто используется.

```
   class RamDisk
    {
    public const string MountPoint = "X:";

    public void createRamDisk()
    {

        try
        {
            string initializeDisk   = "imdisk -a ";
            string imdiskSize       = "-s 1024M ";
            string mountPoint       = "-m "+ MountPoint + " ";


            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo();
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute   = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow    = true;
            procStartInfo.FileName          = "cmd";
            procStartInfo.Arguments         = "/C " + initializeDisk + imdiskSize + mountPoint;
            Process.Start(procStartInfo);

            formatRAMDisk();

        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an Error, while trying to create a ramdisk! Do you have imdisk installed?");
            Console.WriteLine(objException);
        }

    }

    /**
     * since the format option with imdisk doesn't seem to work
     * use the fomat X: command via cmd
     * 
     * as I would say in german:
     * "Von hinten durch die Brust ins Auge"
     * **/
    private void formatRAMDisk(){

        string cmdFormatHDD = "format " + MountPoint + "/Q /FS:NTFS";

        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        password.AppendChar('0');
        password.AppendChar('8');
        password.AppendChar('1');
        password.AppendChar('5');

        ProcessStartInfo formatRAMDiskProcess   = new ProcessStartInfo();
        formatRAMDiskProcess.UseShellExecute    = false;
        formatRAMDiskProcess.CreateNoWindow     = true;
        formatRAMDiskProcess.RedirectStandardInput     = true;
        formatRAMDiskProcess.FileName           = "cmd";
        formatRAMDiskProcess.Verb               = "runas";
        formatRAMDiskProcess.UserName           = "Administrator";
        formatRAMDiskProcess.Password           = password;
        formatRAMDiskProcess.Arguments          = "/C " + cmdFormatHDD;
        Process process                         = Process.Start(formatRAMDiskProcess);

        sendCMDInput(process);
    }

    private void sendCMDInput(Process process)
    {
        StreamWriter inputWriter = process.StandardInput;
        inputWriter.WriteLine("J");
        inputWriter.Flush();
        inputWriter.WriteLine("RAMDisk for valueable data");
        inputWriter.Flush();
    }

    public string getMountPoint()
    {
        return MountPoint;
    }
}
```